# »unterminated string literal« error after copying script

Tags: php, javascript, string, xslt, copy

I have built a little web application with several *.js files. I am using some frameworks, like jQuery and paper.js, too. I made a config.xml file which lists the files, stores variables and so on. Now I am trying to use XSLT to transform this file into one big javascript-file that will be delivered to the client.

All in all there is no problem and it is working fine, as long as i do not include paper.js. If i do this, my firebug gives me the following message:

[image: browsers error message]

This even happens if just copy he whole content of the paper.js file into another, without any additional code. After I compared the original file and the copy it turned out that the original line looks like this:

[image: original line before copy]

That is a screenshot of notepad++ under windows7 64bit.

On server side the script files are opened via:

```
file_get_contents()
```

and included via:

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:function('mygen::getfile', string(text()))" />
```

How can I come arround this issue?? Thanks for help, greetings philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original file, replace the non-printable characters with their correct codes. In particular, that `[NUL]` should be `\0`.

Comment: could give me a little more Detail? Can i do this on serverside with an regular expression?

Comment: Just open the original file in Notepad++, and replace the characters. You only need to do it once, in the file on the server. Mind you, the reason you have any problems in the first place is because you are mixing too many frameworks. If you just used a plain `<script src="paper.js"></script>` tag then you'd be fine.